# Jade syntax indent error with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I got this code in my index.jade where I use bootstrap :

```
block content
  .container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      h1.page-header 1 Col Portfolio
        small Showcase Your Work One Column at a Time
  .row
    .col-lg-7.col-md-7
      a(href='#')
        img.img-responsive(src='http://placehold.it/700x300', alt='')
    .col-lg-5.col-md-5
      h3 Project One
      h4 Subheading
      p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem, adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies, justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.
      a.btn.btn-primary(href='#') View Project
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right 
  hr //**<- problem with this** 
  .row
    .col-lg-7.col-md-7
      a(href='#')
        img.img-responsive(src='http://placehold.it/700x300', alt='')
    .col-lg-5.col-md-5
      h3 Project Two
      h4 Subheading
      p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod     odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem, adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies, justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.
      a.btn.btn-primary(href='#') View Project
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right
```

Everytime I try to add a **hr** tag like I would do in HTML between rows I got a 500 ReferenceError from Express.

Comment: Try to indent `.container` and the first `.row`.

Comment: They are actually already indented in my code. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which consist in including the `hr` in a `row`.

```
  .row
  hr
```

Don't know if it's the best thing to do but works for now !